# jQuery issue with calculating the VAT

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know the examples are differing but thats because the js is mixing up however if the vat is show on both the examples and showing the issue i am having....

first example vat is fine, but second your see its showing as 0.20 and i think s not working correctly when over 1000.... anyone know why when over 1000 does not calculate the 20% correctly?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Hide initial values that need updating
  $("#estimated-shipping em, .cart-finalTotal span, .cart-vat span").hide();
  // get current delivery rate
  $("#get_rate").trigger('click');
  // set a timeout and get total and shipping that was generated and add together for nnew total
  setTimeout(function() {
    // get cart sub-total
    var a = $(".cart-total span").text().replace(/\$|£/gi, "");
    // get estimated shipping cost
    var b = $("#estimated-shipping em").text().replace(/\$|£/, '');
    if (b == "FREE") {
      b = "0.00"
      var isFree = "true";
    } else {
      b = $("#estimated-shipping em").text().replace(/\$|£/, '');
    }
    // add together sub-total and estimated shipping to new total
    var total = a + b;
    total = parseFloat(total.replace(/,/g, ''));
    //add the currency with £ (not sure why it was setting $ before)
    if (isFree == "true") {
      $("#estimated-shipping em").html("FREE");
    } else {
      $("#estimated-shipping em").html("£" + b);
    }
    // update with new total with sub-total and added shipping
    $('.cart-finalTotal span').html("£" + total.toFixed(2).replace(/(^\d{1,3}|\d{3})(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:$|\.))/g, '$1,'));
    // show new values
    $("#estimated-shipping em, .cart-finalTotal span, .cart-vat span").show();
  }, 2000);
  $(".item-quantity input").on("change", function() {
    // let initially disable the input to avoid problems
    $(".item-quantity input").prop("disabled", true);
    // gets auto get rates based on a UK address
    $("#get_rate").trigger('click');
    $("#estimated-shipping em, .cart-finalTotal span, .cart-vat span").hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
      var a = $(".cart-total span").text().replace(/\$|£/gi, "");
      // get estimated shipping cost
      var b = $("#estimated-shipping em").text().replace(/\$|£/, '');
      if (b == "FREE") {
        b = "0.00"
        var isFree = "true";
      } else {
        b = $("#estimated-shipping em").text().replace(/\$|£/, '');
      }
      // add together sub-total and estimated shipping to new total
      var total = a + b;
      total = parseFloat(total.replace(/,/g, ''));
      //add the currency with £ (not sure why it was setting $ before)
      if (isFree == "true") {
        $("#estimated-shipping em").html("FREE");
      } else {
        $("#estimated-shipping em").html("£" + b);
      }
      // update with new total with sub-total and added shipping
      $('.cart-finalTotal span').html("£" + total.toFixed(2).replace(/(^\d{1,3}|\d{3})(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:$|\.))/g, '$1,'));
      // update VAT when input changed
      var oldVAT = $(".cart-total span").text().replace(/\$|£/gi, "");
      var newVAT = (parseFloat(oldVAT.replace(/(^\d{1,3}|\d{3})(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:$|\.))/g, '$1,')) * 20) / 100;
      $(".cart-vat span").html("£" + newVAT.toFixed(2));
      // show all new value updates
      $("#estimated-shipping em, .cart-finalTotal span, .cart-vat span").show();
      // lets enable the quantity input a gain
      $(".item-quantity input").prop("disabled", false);
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>under 1000</h1>
<form action="/cart" method="POST">
  <div class="cart-left">
    <table class="cart-items">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Product</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Sub-total</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>

        <tr data-variant-id="16285032007">
          <td class="item-details">
            <a href="/products/avatar-aubergine-dream-1?variant=16285032007" class="item-thumbnail">
              <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1174/5686/products/Avatar-aubergine-dream_011b6ba4-8681-4969-aad2-fcfc7c83121a_small.jpeg?v=1456749751" alt="Avatar - Aubergine Dream - Cover + Bean Filling (UK only)">
            </a>

            <div class="item-info">
              <p class="item-brand" style="width:30px;"></p>
              <div class="product-brand" itemprop="brand">




                <a href="/collections/vendors?q=Avatar%20Indoor">
                  <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0911/4528/t/5/assets/logo-Avatar.jpg" style="width:100px!important">
                </a>

























































              </div>
              <p></p>
              <p class="item-title"><a href="/products/avatar-aubergine-dream-1?variant=16285032007">Aubergine Dream</a>
              </p>




              <p class="item-variant">Cover + Bean Filling (UK only)</p>





            </div>
          </td>

          <td class="item-price">
            <span class="show-mobile"> PRICE :</span>
            <span class="money">£199.00</span>
          </td>

          <td class="item-quantity">
            <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="4" value="7" data-variant-id="16285032007">
          </td>

          <td class="item-line-price">
            <span class="show-mobile">SUB-TOTAL :</span>
            <span class="money" data-currency="GBP">£398.00</span>
          </td>

          <td class="item-remove">
            <a href="/cart/change/16285032007?quantity=0"><i class="icon-cross"></i></a>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>

    <a href="/" class="cart-continue button button-primary">Continue Shopping</a>


    <div class="cart-instructions">
      <p>
        <label for="cart-note">Add a note to your order</label>
        <textarea id="cart-note" rows="4" name="note"></textarea>
      </p>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="cart-right">


    <p class="cart-total">Sub-Total<span class="money" data-currency="GBP">£398.00</span>
    </p>
    <p class="cart-vat">VAT 20% (included)<span class="money" style="display: block;">£79.60</span>
    </p>
    <p class="cart-delivery">Delivery (estimated)<span class="money" id="estimated-shipping">+ <em style="display: inline;">£9.00</em></span>
    </p>
    <p class="cart-finalTotal">Total<span class="money" style="display: block;">£398.01</span>
    </p>
    <div class="cart-checkout">


      <button class="button button-primary button-add-to-cart button-pay-now" type="submit" name="checkout"><span class="icom-lock"></span>Pay Now</button>

      <br>
      <br>


      <div class="additional-checkout-buttons">
        <p>Or checkout with</p>
        <img id="applePayButton" style="display: none" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" onload="typeof createApplyPayButton === 'function' ? createApplyPayButton(this) : window.addEventListener('applePayReady', (function(){createApplyPayButton(this)}).bind(this))">
        <input type="image" name="goto_pp" value="paypal_express" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</form>

<h1>over 1000</h1>

<form action="/cart" method="POST">
  <div class="cart-left">
    <table class="cart-items">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Product</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Sub-total</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>

        <tr data-variant-id="16285032007">
          <td class="item-details">
            <a href="/products/avatar-aubergine-dream-1?variant=16285032007" class="item-thumbnail">
              <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1174/5686/products/Avatar-aubergine-dream_011b6ba4-8681-4969-aad2-fcfc7c83121a_small.jpeg?v=1456749751" alt="Avatar - Aubergine Dream - Cover + Bean Filling (UK only)">
            </a>

            <div class="item-info">
              <p class="item-brand" style="width:30px;"></p>
              <div class="product-brand" itemprop="brand">




                <a href="/collections/vendors?q=Avatar%20Indoor">
                  <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0911/4528/t/5/assets/logo-Avatar.jpg" style="width:100px!important">
                </a>

























































              </div>
              <p></p>
              <p class="item-title"><a href="/products/avatar-aubergine-dream-1?variant=16285032007">Aubergine Dream</a>
              </p>




              <p class="item-variant">Cover + Bean Filling (UK only)</p>





            </div>
          </td>

          <td class="item-price">
            <span class="show-mobile"> PRICE :</span>
            <span class="money">£199.00</span>
          </td>

          <td class="item-quantity">
            <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="4" value="7" data-variant-id="16285032007">
          </td>

          <td class="item-line-price">
            <span class="show-mobile">SUB-TOTAL :</span>
            <span class="money" data-currency="GBP">£1,194.00</span>
          </td>

          <td class="item-remove">
            <a href="/cart/change/16285032007?quantity=0"><i class="icon-cross"></i></a>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>

    <a href="/" class="cart-continue button button-primary">Continue Shopping</a>


    <div class="cart-instructions">
      <p>
        <label for="cart-note">Add a note to your order</label>
        <textarea id="cart-note" rows="4" name="note"></textarea>
      </p>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="cart-right">


    <p class="cart-total">Sub-Total<span class="money" data-currency="GBP">£1,194.00</span>
    </p>
    <p class="cart-vat">VAT 20% (included)<span class="money" style="display: block;">£0.20</span>
    </p>
    <p class="cart-delivery">Delivery (estimated)<span class="money" id="estimated-shipping">+ <em style="display: inline;">FREE</em></span>
    </p>
    <p class="cart-finalTotal">Total<span class="money" style="display: block;">£1,194.00</span>
    </p>
    <div class="cart-checkout">


      <button class="button button-primary button-add-to-cart button-pay-now" type="submit" name="checkout"><span class="icom-lock"></span>Pay Now</button>

      <br>
      <br>


      <div class="additional-checkout-buttons">
        <p>Or checkout with</p>
        <img id="applePayButton" style="display: none" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" onload="typeof createApplyPayButton === 'function' ? createApplyPayButton(this) : window.addEventListener('applePayReady', (function(){createApplyPayButton(this)}).bind(this))">
        <input type="image" name="goto_pp" value="paypal_express" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: You've put a ton of code and markup here; can you create a more minimal representation of the problem you're having?

Comment: Let me create a better example.... give me  a few mins

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/acwmbxo9/ - this has the set vaalues for over 1,000 it is working fine when below 1,000 and works out the vat fine but over 1,000 just shows as 0.20